# ASP MVC ActionFilterAttribute OnActionExecuting not fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction, actionfilterattribute

I have 2 controllers `Home` with

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                // do some irrelevant stuff
                    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);           

            }

    public ActionResult Index()
            {            
                    return View();
            }
}
```

and `Service` with

```
public ActionResult Confirm()
            { return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");}
```

And one `ActionFilterAttribute` with `OnActionExecuting` method

```
 public class InvitationModeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
               // do some stuff

                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            }
}

public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {            
            filters.Add(new InvitationModeAttribute());
        }
    }
```

When I go to `localhost/Service/Confirm` , `OnActionExecuting` is fired, but then when `RedirectToAction` is called, `OnActionExecuting` is not fired.
How can I catch this after `RedirectToAction`?

Thanks

Comment: Show the code of both controllers.

Comment: edited... the point is that OnActionExecuting is not fired after RedirectToAction

Comment: Where you have written your OnActionExecuting method ?

Comment: @Maarty I don't see attributes. have you decorated both actions with desired attribute?

Comment: @Kamo - nope, what attribute I need here?

Comment: I think you might need to add attribute if you are not writing that OnActionExecuting method in your controller itself. From what you have posted i see that for one you are writing in Home controller and for the other controller also you have write that way in controller otherwise you need to add your custom attribute and then decorate it for the methods

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)  For More clarity

First of all 
Remove OnActionExecuting method in controller level

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
       [InvitationModeAttribute]
     public ActionResult Index()
     {            
        return View();
     }
 }
```

2nd Controller

```
 public class ServiceController : Controller
 {
   [InvitationModeAttribute]
   public ActionResult Confirm()
   { 
     return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }
 }
```

From MSDN

> Scope of Action Filters
>
> In addition to marking individual action methods with an action
>   filter, you can mark a controller class as a whole with an action
>   filter. In that case, the filter applies to all action methods of that
>   controller. Additionally, if your controller derives from another
>   controller, the base controller might have its own action-filter
>   attributes. Likewise, if your controller overrides an action method
>   from a base controller, the method might have its own action-filter
>   attributes and those it inherits from the overridden action method. To
>   make it easier to understand how action filters work together, action
>   methods are grouped into scopes. A scope defines where the attribute
>   applies, such as whether it marks a class or a method, and whether it
>   marks a base class or a derived class.

Comment: Thanks. Well it works. But it is not what I want.. Anyway I am definitely doing wrong approach.. What I need is to know in HomeController that it was being redirected from Service controller. I want it for all methods there, so I don't want to use any cookies or parameters for every single redirect. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I am afraid you cant do it AFAIK.